# how to mark a row as dead or used after using it in the java program

Tags: java, mysql

i have a table called user_request

```
 req_id    user_id       name        num_of_seats     startplace
     1         11        arjun          3              Mumbai
     2         12        chethan        2              delhi
     3         13         raj           4              pune
```

I have a java program that uses above details to schedule the seats which selects the first user_id on the table, so that the first request is performed,

```
stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
{
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt
            .executeQuery("SELECT num_of_seats FROM user_request ORDER BY req_id ASC LIMIT 1");
    while (rs1.next()) {
        size = rs1.getInt("num_of_seats");
        System.out.println("the number of seats requested:-" + size);
    }

    //
    code to perform scheduling using the details retrieved

    //
```

now after this in the next run of the program I want the program to select the second row, so that the query should select the items from the second row and then the third,  how can I do that??? I'm not getting a proper idea.. please help me...

Comment: Why do you not load the whole table from database and process it in your java application?

Comment: Have a column in the table and flag it when the seat scheduling is done for a particular user

Comment: @sadhu thank you.. can you just give me a example. so after the scheduling I should use a mysql query to set each flag??

Comment: Yes. After scheduling execute an update query - Update user_request set seated=1 where req_id=?

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to do it is to get everything out and then loop it within the java program.
The way you are doing it will put a lot more stress on the server/DB which under 99% of the case is MUCH slower than running some checking in the program itself.

try this 
(sorry don't have an easy way to check my code, so it MIGHT have syntax error, but a least you'll get the idea)

```
                   stmt1 = conn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT num_of_seats FROM user_request ORDER BY req_id");
                    int[] size = null; 
                    if (rs1.next()) {
                         size = (int[])rs1.getArray("num_of_seats").getArray();
                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<size.length;i++){
                          System.out.println("the number of seats requested:-" +size[i]);
                    }
```